# How to transform scraping results into dict to create data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page where I have the following code:

```
<li>
<span class="name">Person One</span>
<span class="organization">Mall</span>
<span class="employee">-Yes<span class="contractor yes">Yes</span></span>
</li>

<li>
<span class="name">Person Two</span>
<span class="organization">Market</span>
<span class="employee">-Yes<span class="contractor yes">Yes</span></span>
</li>

<li>
<span class="name">Person Three</span>
<span class="organization">Mall</span>
<span class="employee">-Yes<span class="contractor no">No</span></span>
</li>
```

I already found the class where those tags are located with `bs4`. My goal is to get each of these span classes and then order that into a dict to transform it into a dataframe.

I'm really stuck at this point! Any help would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract key from span class and value from its text with `dict comprehension`:

```
{x.get('class')[0]: x.text for x in li.select('span')}
```

*Cause `x.get('class')` will result in a list, we have to pick the first of its element(s) to make `list comprehension` work.*

Adjustment to values of employee, caused of nested `<span>`s:

```
df['employee'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['employee'].strip('-').split(x['contractor'], 1)), axis=1)
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html='''
<li>
<span class="name">Person One</span>
<span class="organization">Mall</span>
<span class="employee">-Yes<span class="contractor yes">Yes</span></span>
</li>

<li>
<span class="name">Person Two</span>
<span class="organization">Market</span>
<span class="employee">-Yes<span class="contractor yes">Yes</span></span>
</li>

<li>
<span class="name">Person Three</span>
<span class="organization">Mall</span>
<span class="employee">-Yes<span class="contractor no">No</span></span>
</li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []
for li in soup.select('li'):
    data.append({x.get('class')[0]: x.text for x in li.select('span')})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['employee'] = df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['employee'].strip('-').split(x['contractor'], 1)), axis=1)
df
```

#### Output

| name | organization | employee | contractor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person One | Mall | Yes | Yes |
| Person Two | Market | Yes | Yes |
| Person Three | Mall | Yes | No |

Comment: The page that I'm trying to scrap have those <span> tags nested indeed. Could you explain the logic behind your code? I didn't quite understand the x.get('class')[0]. But it worked as I was expecting, thank you!

Comment: Added adjustment for dataframe and explanition concerning your question - We can not use list (of classes) as value, so we have to pick the one and only available class name.